# SetDate with Statement?

Tags: java, date, jdbc, prepared-statement

With `PreparedStatement`, you just call `SetDate` and be done with it.

How do you pass in a `Date` with a regular `Statement`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the DBMS you are using, each one can use a different format for date literals.

For example in Oracle, you use:

```
UPDATE table SET DATEFIELD = DATE '1998-12-25'
```

In MySQL:

```
UPDATE table SET DATEFIELD = '1998-12-25'
```

Etc.

I would recommend to continue using `PreparedStatement` to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Is there any helper method in JDBC which abstracts this process?

Comment: Wouldn't think so, and I would avoid it because it will make your applications vulnerable to SQL Injection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Note that JDBC escapes are part of JDBC standard, not just a feature of PostgreSQL JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

You just construct the  regular statement using the string and the function provided by DBMS  to convert a string to the date .

Most DBMS should have such function .For example , Oracle have a `to_date()` .( eg: `to_date('2012/01/02', 'yyyy/mm/dd')` .